# Is there a way to reference an issue including title on GitHub?

Tags: github, github-flavored-markdown

I know that I can reference an issue just by giving the issue number like this: `#123`. This way the title of the issues shows up on hovering the number. But I have a main issue, where I want to aggregate all dependent issues. In order to do this I want to include in the description a list of issues and have the titles inline, like this:

```
My frontend issues
- #32 Fix unclosed HTLM tags
- #36 Remove unsupported tags
- #41 Split very complex templates into blocks
- #44 Give all images an alt attribute
```

Is there a way to do this so that the the comment stays up to date if i update the actual issue title?

I've searched [here](https://help.github.com/articles/writing-on-github/#references) and [here](https://guides.github.com/features/issues/#notifications), but can't find a way to do this.

Comment: You mean for example, if you change the title of issue #32 from  `#32...HTLM` to `#32...HTML`, you'd want this change to reflect on your summary issue ?

Comment: @CyrilDD: yes I am aiming for this, but if it is not possible, then at least can GitHub insert the title for me the one time? The same mechanism as on if it were on hovering the issue number.

Comment: I don't know about possible existing solutions. However, you can use the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/) and code a script that would do that. Not sure it's worth the trouble anyways, unless you are really dealing with a lot of issues.

Comment: Issue reference with title seems to be implemented for lists but not for paragraphs: https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/1020#issuecomment-878483070

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any way to automatically update the title of referenced issues without messing with the GitHub API, at the moment. You can suggest such feature over here: [GitHub Community](https://github.community).

It might be a good idea for you to make sure that your title is prime before referencing it - setting standard title conventions for your repository may help with that.

Comment: Anyone who wants this feature implemented should upvote the related issue on GitHub, https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/1020

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy the issue you linked (#1020) was archived at some point since Aug 1, 2021. As of the time of writing this, the current active community discussion is at https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/4321 (unanswered, but open).